# Tensorflow Lite: Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Destination type INT32 is not supported

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I create a simple model with tensorflow, that int32 in, process, probability out.

Then saved as tflite file, import to Android with right-click menu in Android Studio. It show me sample code and I use it as it. But replacing `context` to `getApplicationContext()` and `byteBuffer` with a function `int2ByteBuffer(int i)`.

Then I received "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Destination type INT32 is not supported." message. I have no clue what could go wrong. Please help me, it's driving me crazy.

```java
private ByteBuffer int2ByteBuffer(int i) {
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE);
    b.clear();
    b.putInt(i);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Could you post this feature request at the TensorFlow GitHub? (hub.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) Looks like there is a room for improvements in TensorFlow Lite Android API.

Comment: I still figure out whether I code wrong or just the API's problem. In the official tutorial, it wrote "The wrapper code removes the need to interact directly with ByteBuffer. Instead, developers can interact with the TensorFlow Lite model with typed objects such as Bitmap and Rect.". But indeed, the generated sample with byte buffer. I'm a beginner to this whole thing (python, TensorFlow, Keras, android), and idk which part could go wrong.

[Generate model interfaces using metadata](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/codegen